# Linestring sides missing after exploding GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas

I have been trying to find what I am actually doing wrong for a day now and can't figure out what the problem with my approach might be. So, a little background is in place:

I have a dataframe with a bunch of coordinates:

```
index                                    id  x_polygon  y_polygon  \
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      27.03      38.58   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      28.26      38.58   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      28.26      44.38   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      27.03      44.38   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      27.03      38.58   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      28.26      38.58   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      28.26      44.38   
3      3  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      27.03      44.38   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3      32.99      37.25   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3      33.57      37.25   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3      33.57      44.86   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3      32.99      44.86   
5      5  5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d      19.03      45.93   
5      5  5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d      31.39      45.93   
5      5  5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d      31.39      46.52   
5      5  5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d      19.03      46.52   

                               edges.id  edges.linkable  
3  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True  
3  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True  
3  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True  
3  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True  
3  e49832f7-af6b-4da3-b2c2-8a66cb16cc39            True  
3  e49832f7-af6b-4da3-b2c2-8a66cb16cc39            True  
3  e49832f7-af6b-4da3-b2c2-8a66cb16cc39            True  
3  e49832f7-af6b-4da3-b2c2-8a66cb16cc39            True  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d            True  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d            True  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d            True  
0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d            True  
5  8395d1d1-b676-43a0-92dd-e4038df9549c            True  
5  8395d1d1-b676-43a0-92dd-e4038df9549c            True  
5  8395d1d1-b676-43a0-92dd-e4038df9549c            True  
5  8395d1d1-b676-43a0-92dd-e4038df9549c            True
```

Here is a dict-version of it:

```
{'index': {3: 3, 0: 0, 5: 5}, 'id': {3: '13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1', 0: '168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3', 5: '5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d'}, 'x_polygon': {3: 27.031515, 0: 32.987843, 5: 19.034254}, 'y_polygon': {3: 44.37576, 0: 44.86328, 5: 46.517555}, 'edges.id': {3: 'e49832f7-af6b-4da3-b2c2-8a66cb16cc39', 0: 'ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d', 5: '8395d1d1-b676-43a0-92dd-e4038df9549c'}, 'edges.linkable': {3: True, 0: True, 5: True}}
```

I transform the coordinates into POLYGON objects

```
geostore_obstacles_geometry = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geostore_obstacles.groupby(['id']).apply(
    lambda g: Polygon(gpd.points_from_xy(g['x_polygon'], g['y_polygon']))))

geostore_obstacles_geometry = geostore_obstacles_geometry.reset_index()
geostore_obstacles_geometry
```

which returns:

```
                                id  \
0  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1   
1  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   
2  5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d   

                                            geometry  
0  POLYGON ((27.03151 38.58253, 28.26146 38.58253...  
1  POLYGON ((32.98784 37.25187, 33.56717 37.25187...  
2  POLYGON ((19.03425 45.92993, 31.38868 45.92993...
```

and merge with the original dataframe. The reason I am doing this is that I also want every point as a geometrical object POINT:

```
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points = geostore_obstacles_geometry.merge(geostore_obstacles, left_on =['id'],right_on =['id'])
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points =geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points.rename_geometry('geometry_obstacle')
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points['x_polygon'], geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_points['y_polygon']))
```

which gives:

```
                               id  \
0  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1   
1  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1   
2  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1   

                                   geometry_obstacle  index  x_polygon  \
0  POLYGON ((27.03151 38.58253, 28.26146 38.58253...      3      27.03   
1  POLYGON ((27.03151 38.58253, 28.26146 38.58253...      3      28.26   
2  POLYGON ((27.03151 38.58253, 28.26146 38.58253...      3      28.26   

   y_polygon                              edges.id  edges.linkable  \
0      38.58  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   
1      38.58  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   
2      44.38  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   

                    geometry  
0  POINT (27.03151 38.58253)  
1  POINT (28.26146 38.58253)  
2  POINT (28.26146 44.37576)
```

My objective from here is to split all the boundaries of the polygons in its individual edges and the way I found to do this is first by using `gemgis` and explode the polygons into LINESTRING  objects (which are the boundaries) and then use `shapely.os.split` to split the linestrings at the points I determined above:

```
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints=geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints.rename(columns ={'geometry_obstacle':'geometry', 'geometry':'point'})
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints['geometry'] = geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints['geometry'].buffer(0)
geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints = gemgis.vector.explode_polygons(gdf=geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints)
def get_side_of_rect(row, linecol="geometry", pointcol="point"):
    return split(row[linecol], row[pointcol])

Full_geometry = (
    geostore_obstacles_geometry_with_geopoints.assign(sides=lambda df: df.apply(get_side_of_rect, axis=1))
)
Full_geometry = Full_geometry.set_geometry('sides')

exploded = Full_geometry.explode(ignore_index=False)
exploded = exploded.reset_index()
Full_geometry = exploded.drop(['geometry'], axis=1)
Full_geometry


level_0  level_1                                    id  index  x_polygon  \
0        0        0  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      3      27.03   
1        1        0  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      3      28.26   
2        1        1  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      3      28.26   
3        2        0  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      3      28.26   
4        2        1  13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1      3      28.26   

   y_polygon                              edges.id  edges.linkable  \
0      38.58  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   
1      38.58  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   
2      38.58  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   
3      44.38  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   
4      44.38  66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff            True   

                       point  \
0  POINT (27.03151 38.58253)   
1  POINT (28.26146 38.58253)   
2  POINT (28.26146 38.58253)   
3  POINT (28.26146 44.37576)   
4  POINT (28.26146 44.37576)   

                                               sides  
0  LINESTRING (27.03151 38.58253, 27.03151 44.375...  
1  LINESTRING (27.03151 38.58253, 27.03151 44.375...  
2  LINESTRING (28.26146 38.58253, 27.03151 38.58253)  
3  LINESTRING (27.03151 38.58253, 27.03151 44.375...  
4  LINESTRING (28.26146 44.37576, 28.26146 38.582...
```

As you see, I have the sides of the polygons. And I can determine those that have only 2 vertices by first calculating the number of vertices of each LINESTRING and then selecting what I want:

```
Full_geometry = Full_geometry.rename(columns={'id':'id_gondola','edges.id':'edges_id'})

n_vertices=[] 

for i, row in Full_geometry.iterrows():
    ls= row.sides.type.startswith("LINE")
    if ls:
        n = 0
        for part in row.sides:
            n += len(part.coords)
    else:
        n = len(row.sides.coords)
    n_vertices.append(n)

Full_geometry["n_vertices"] = n_vertices

Full_geometry_complete = Full_geometry[Full_geometry['n_vertices']==2]
print(len(Full_geometry_complete))
Full_geometry_complete = Full_geometry_complete.drop(['level_0','level_1'], axis=1).drop_duplicates()
Full_geometry_complete = Full_geometry_complete.reset_index()
Full_geometry_complete['part'] = Full_geometry_complete['level_0'].astype(str)

Full_geometry_complete['Facing_sub'] = Full_geometry_complete.id_gondola.str.cat(Full_geometry_complete.edges_id.astype(str), sep='_')
Full_geometry_complete['Facing'] = Full_geometry_complete.Facing_sub.str.cat(Full_geometry_complete.part.astype(str), sep='_')
Full_geometry_complete = Full_geometry_complete.drop(['level_0','id_gondola','edges_id','part','Facing_sub'], axis=1)
```

But now, if I plot these, I only have half of the edges (they should be rectangles and I should be able to plot any of these sides individually). I would like to know what I am doing wrong and/or have an easier way to get all sides as unique objects.

[image]